# how to update single column and multiple rows in mysql using single query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert-update

MYSQL table -> T(player,id)

I am trying to update this MYSQL table for same(only one) id and 10 different players.
I did this.

```
for($k=0;$k<10;$k++)
    {       
       echo $newPlayer[$k];

       $que = "UPDATE `players` SET `player`='".$newPlayer[$k]."' WHERE `id`='".$id."'";
       $db_con->exec($que);
    }
```

when i echo $newPlayer array, it displays correct values so why the query doesn't work.

11 rows should be added to the table 'T' with 11 different player values and same id value.
but only one player value gets added to table. why??

Comment: Where does your variable `$id` (at the end of the query) come from? Also, please use something to escape your values in SQL, such as [PDOStatement.bindParam()](http://php.net/pdostatement.bindparam).

Comment: `update` does not insert anything. An `insert` query would

Comment: Tomas Creemers, id is set before the for loop. and Id is not problem, 'player'is.

Comment: Each time, this query updates all ten rows with value of $newPlayer[$k]. So at the end of loop, all the ten rows will have value of $newplayer[9]

Comment: so what u suggest, rakeshjain??

Answer (score 0):

The `update`  statement is used for update data not for insert data. So with the update you can only change what is already on a table, nothing new would be created.

If you want to insert new data you should use `insert` statement.

With the command you post you are saying to the database

Hey man change the attribute `player` with the value `'".$newPlayer[$k]."'` where the `id`of the table `playear` is `'".$id."'"`

So as discussed in the comments here is a better solution for you:

```
update players p, 
  (select id, player, substring_index( substring_index(lst, ',', idx), ',', -1) as pl
     from (select p.*, @number := @number+1 as idx, lst 
             from players p,
                 (select @number := 0 as nb) n,
                 (select 'i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p' as lst) lst) x ) a 
set p.player = a.pl
where p.id = a.id 
  and p.player = a.player
```

But for the PHP you will have to make your array `$newPlayer` as a string separated by a `,` without spaces in between.

Something like this:

```
$newNames = implode(",",$newPlayer);

 $que = "update players p, 
      (select id, player, substring_index( substring_index(lst, ',', idx), ',', -1) as pl
         from (select p.*, @number := @number+1 as idx, lst 
                 from players p,
                     (select @number := 0 as nb) n,
                     (select '$newNames' as lst) lst) x ) a 
    set p.player = a.pl
    where p.id = a.id 
      and p.player = a.player";

$db_con->exec($que);
```

With this you wont need the `for`

Comment: TABLE [(a,3),(b,3),(c,3),(d,3),(e,3),(f,3),(g,3),(h,3),(i,3),(j,3)],This is before UPDATE. I have an array $newPlayer with values (k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t). Now after UPDATE above table should look like this (replacing above 10 rows). TABLE[(k,3),(l,3),(m,3),(n,3),(o,3),(p,3),(q,3),(r,3),(s,3),(t,3),].

Comment: Ok, I undertand now. So your code is wrong because of what @rakeshjain said.

Comment: The order of the data matters? Because if it matter you can't do what you want without another condition on your where clause.